# How to Change VideoView Requests from GET to POST method

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, android-videoview

Hello Please i want Help, i have server only accept POST requests to Download Video, So how i can make VideoView send **POST** requests to Download Buffer Video From my Host

i tryed to change headers,I found that the method cannot be changed through the header

```
Map headers = new HashMap();
headers.put("Cookie","CloudFront-Policy=xx; Domain=xx; Path=xx");
headers.put("User-Agent","My Agent");
String u ="http://192.168.0.173/1.mp4";
VideoView videoplayer = findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(u);
videoplayer.setVideoURI(uri,headers);
videoplayer.start()
```

When the application starts to run it is sent to download the video using **GET** Requests
How i can Change Video Requests When Download Buffer To **POST**

my Logs Server
"GET /1.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 1101928 "-" "MY Agent"

i want to Change To
"POST /1.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 1101928 "-" "MY Agent"

Comment: In Android, The VideoView class doesn't support sending POST requests to download video. Maybe a good solution could be change the strategy, replacing VideoView by ExoPlayer.

Comment: @aldajo92 Thanks for your comment, I already used **ExoPlayer** but I still can't do it, if you can help me with ExoPlayer I will be very thankful to you because I don't know how to change the method To **POST**